# How did "heart" come to refer to the shape?

Tags: etymology

When and why was this first called a *heart*?

[image]

As far as I can tell, the biological heart does not appear to bear it much resemblance.

Comment: I wondered that since my childhood. Guess I will know now. Ty ELU...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the symbol has developed as a metaphorical use of a [Fig leaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fig_leaf) to [ivy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedera_helix) and was inconized as the symbol you posted.

Unfortunately I haven't found citable sources in English.

Answer (score 1):

A [Slate article](http://www.slate.com/id/2159800/?GT1=9129) addresses this, as does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_%28symbol%29#As_an_Icon).

Comment: Link rot happens: please include summaries of the articles you link to.

Comment: My point was more that this information is easily available with a quick Google search.

Comment: If you believe this question is general reference, you should have either voted to close it as such (if you have that privilege), or flagged it for moderator attention. Posting an answer implies that you believe the question is valid and on-topic. (Also, having read both of your links, I don't see that they satisfactorily answer this question.)

Comment: Yes, this is a google query.  "heart shape origin" yields besides the above, these relevant [Google Answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/383401.html) and [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080123223720AACAYHL) links. Not a language issue, either.

Comment: The answer should at least include the full description of the Slate article, which is "The Shape of My Heart/ Where did the ubiquitous Valentine's symbol come from?" By Keelin McDonell
Posted Tuesday, Feb. 13, 2007, at 5:20 PM ET as it is in an archived section of old content from Slate.